# Angular Universal Passing Data in request header

Tags: angular, .net-core, server-side-rendering

I am working with angular(12) universal and in the backend, using .net core 3.1.

My app is like crm. My question is taking company identifier from url.

Eg; my angular app url format is companyidentifier.myapp.com/rest_of_urls.
I need to add subdomain information from angular app requests that are sent to server apis.
I checked all states like headers (referer, origin or custom header), getting url information in server side. These are sent to SSR.
When SSR try to render page, i couldn't see these headers or url information in the server side.

How can i able to share a data that can be used in SSR rendering?
I need to update server api requests headers or something else during rendering.

Comment: Hi, i know for a fact that `httpContext.Request.Path == "/index.html"`, the real url resides in the `httpContext.Request.Features.RawTarget` private property. But aren't you able to read the hoststring from `httpContext.Request.Host`?

Comment: hi, i solved the problem with transferState in platform browser. At server.ts i can take client url with req.header.host. And i transfered this information to angular with trasfer state. Also i can check if it browser call or server side call in angular app with isPlatformBrowser. So if it's a server side call i can able to get host information on client side.

Answer (score 1):

The [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/universal#using-absolute-urls-for-http-data-requests-on-the-server) recommend passing the URL through the `options` param of `renderModuleFactory`

> The recommended solution is to pass the full request URL to the options argument of renderModule() or renderModuleFactory() (depending on what you use to render AppServerModule on the server). This option is the least intrusive as it does not require any changes to the application.

From this tutorial on SSR in ASP you can see an example

- https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-2022-version-7aaed8157976

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am using iisnode for serving angular app. Do you have any solution for iisnode?